# Can I generate & transmit ACARS message via software?

Tags: acars

Is there any software available for generating ACARS message? If yes how to transmit that over RF?.

I want to do that for academic purpose. My settings are GNU radio and HackRF one.

Comment: Welcome to [Aviation.se]. Please take the [tour] to help understand how this site is different than your run-of-the-mill discussion forum. Then, if you'll take a look in the [help] under "asking", you'll see that "resource location" questions are explicitly off topic.

Comment: For transmitting, you might ask on [Amateur Radio Stack Exchange](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) as rules can vary depending on country.

Comment: If you are going to generate and transmit them, do you have the appropriate equipment to receive and decode it? Are you taking precautions to avoid transmitting outside of a controlled area (faraday cage)?

Answer (score 2):

You are unlikely to have a permission for sending technical messages over radio channels used by real aircraft.

But if you just want to make your drone to send you ACARS messages over WiFi, there are [144 open source projects](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=acars&s=stars&type=Repositories) currently on GitHub to deal with these messages. Most of them are parsers, not senders, but anyway selecting the best projects and then understanding the code should give enough insights about the message format. Also, parsers can be used for checking that your sender works properly.